# dataGridView1 doesn't display data from a specified table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

> This code block is supposed to be a sign-up form. Project has several
>   Forms needed to be attached to one another. When you run the project a
>   LOGIN form first appears on the screen with its two textBoxes labelled
>   as (Username, Password) and two buttons (sign-in , sign-up). After the
>   sign-up process which sends all your information with **"insert into"**
>   command  into the **USERStable** in database, you have to type your
>   "username" and "password" into the displayed textboxes correctly,
>   they should match the following "GetString(1)" and "GetString(2)", and
>   then by pressing "sign-up" button bam, you should have **"CONTACTS FORM"**
>   popped up on the screen. CONTACTS FORM has a dataGridView which is
>   supposed to display all the rows that **USERStable** has. In order to
>   prevent users from getting in with wrong Username and Password, I used if
>   statement inside the while loop. It works but when you get in,
>   dataGridVew doesn't display any information. However without a while loop it does.
>   I couldn't figure out the reason where the problem lays on.  Do you have any
>   suggestions?
>
> One  thing I forgot to point out. I've also created a class named USERS with 
>   fields and properties:
>
> string username;
>
> string password;
>
> On the top you can see I've created an object with reference "us".

```
public partial class LOGIN : Form
    {
        public LOGIN()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
USERS us = new USERS();
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               CONTACTS contact = new CONTACTS(); //FORM CONTACT
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = DESKTOP-9I0BNAS\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = CAVID; Integrated Security = True";
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM  users", con);

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }


                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    us.Username = dr.GetString(1);
                    us.Password = dr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                    if(us.Username == textBox1.Text &&
                          us.Password == textBox2.Text)

                    {
                        contact.Show();
                        dataTable.Load(dr);
                        contact.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;            
                        this.Hide();
                        break;
                    }

                }         
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the only info for the current username or is the current username supposed to be getting all the records from the users table?

Comment: there're only two fields in the Users class since I only need these two data for signing in. I retrieve all the rows with *select * command since they have to be displayed in the dataGridviewer but I use only two of them inside the LOGIN form class for IF statement.

Comment: You don't need the while loop to populate the dataTable. Try calling dataTable.Load(dr) with out the while loop. Once the dataTable is populated you can loop it to make decisions whether or not to display the contact form and or dataGridView.